# The proper way to use NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I have a problem that I can't get my head around, and am hoping someone could give me a hint or help.

I have a table, which contains 7 objects. When pressing one of the object the user is presented with a new table, corresponding to the pressed objects. Inside this table the user is able to press an 'Add' button, taking them to a new table where they can choose the objects for table 2.

Table 1 and table 3 (the first and the last) do not need to be edited in, however table 2 needs to. I need to add the data the user pick from table 3 and save it when entering the app again after it has been closed.

In table 1 there is always 7 objects. And needs to be able to have a different table 2.
So I am not sure if the best way is to create 7 different arrays.

I have looked, and have been using, `NSUserDefaults` before, however i am not sure what a good way to approach this is, when using `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Try this link : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/07/nsuserdefault-usage.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to get your array out of the userdefaults modify it then rewrite it back into the userdefaults.
Getting array:

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourKey"]mutableCopy];
```

Setting array:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:yourArray forKey:@"yourKey"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Or use dictionaries and nest them

```
NSMutableDictionary *yourDict1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"yourKey1"]mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *yourDict2 = [[yourDict1 valueForKey:@"yourKey2"]mutableCopy];

    // THIS WILL ADD DATA TO YOUR DICTIONARY
[yourDict2 setValue:@"value" forKey:@"key"];

    // THIS WILL GET DATA FROM YOUR DICTIONARY
NSString *tempStr = [yourDict2 valueForKey:@"keyToGet"];

    // This will write your sub dictionary to your main dictionary
[yourDict1 setObject: yourDict2 forKey:@"yourKey2"];

    // This will write your main dictionary back out to user defaults
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject: yourDict1 forKey:@"yourKey1"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
[yourDict1 release];
[yourDict2 release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ian. But apologize for my lack of knowledge, i am trying to go for the Dictionary way, but can't seem to figure out what is going on in the nesting. Why two? And how would i add the data using that way, and getting it again?

Comment: You said you wanted to have an array within an array for things as i understood it so that's why I suggested the nesting. As far as getting the data out, you can add the items from the dictionary into an array or individual strings.